# Use variable variables with superglobal arrays

Tags: php, variables, dynamic, superglobals

I wonder if is possible to read dynamically superglobal variables, I would like to do something like that:

```
<?php

    $n = 'GET';
    $var = '$_'.$n.'[\'something\']'; // pour lire $_GET['something'] 
    echo $var;

//Or 

    $n = 'POST';
    $var = '$_'.$n.'[\'something\']'; // pour lire $_POST['something'] 
    echo $var;

?>
```

This code don't work as I want, but I would like to know if is workable in PHP?

Comment: Would you please post your complete code? why you want to do this that way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't use [variable variables](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php) with superglobals, functions or class methods and not with `$this`.

And a quote from the manual (It's right before the user comments if you search it):

> **Warning:**
>   Please note that **variable variables cannot** be used with PHP's **Superglobal** arrays within **functions** or **class methods**. The variable **$this** is also a special variable that cannot be referenced dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you is exactelly what I search

But we can't use that into function please?

```
$n = '_GET';

// don't work => Undefined variable: _GET
function f($n) {
    echo ${$n}['a'];
}
f($n);

//work fine
echo ${$n}['a'];
```